# Android studio not start in Ubuntu 12.04 with NoClassDefFoundException

Tags: java, ubuntu, android-studio, wubi

I have Ubuntu installed through Wubi. When I try to start Android Studio it throws me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Toolkit
    at java.awt.Component.<clinit>(Component.java:595)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:190)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:177)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:80)
```

I've read that it could be problem with `libxtst6:i386` in 64-bit systems, but I've installed it and it's not work for me.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: What version of java are you running? Did you install ia32-libs?

Comment: If you want to save yourself a lot of issue down the road then consider removing the Ubuntu wubi install and either dual-booting Ubuntu with your current OS or run Ubuntu in a virtual machine such as Virtualbox.

Comment: all right, I haven't ia32-libs. I installed it and all works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me, when launching IntelliJ Idea, on which Android Studio is based. I had the error because I mistakenly launched the IDE with a 32-bit JDK on my 64-bit system (I have several JDK's on my system). Using the 64-bit JDK solves the problem without requiring installing 32-bit native libraries.